# Where can I connect RO drain saddle?

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens

I'm trying to install an RO system and I have it 99% complete except the drain saddle. I don't see any room for me to install it.
There's not enough space in the elbow and the vertical black pipe is too thick. What are my options?

[image]
[image: saddle]

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, the image didn't want to work.

Comment: Isn't that a dishwasher drain hose coming in from the left top of the InSinkErator? How about tapping into that?

Comment: Do I need something else to plug into instead of he drain saddle? The saddle seems a lot wider.  http://imgur.com/KtrAFRy    Or just drill a hole into the dishwasher drain hose and just plug the RO tube in?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a product like this [drain line adapter](http://www.premierh2o.com/products/premier__164020_dishwasher-_garbage_disposal_drain_line_adapter), instead of the saddle. That would allow you to connect both the RO, and dishwasher drain into the disposal.

[image]